# permissions setup Facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-invite

I tried many facebook codes to send invitation to my facebook friends 
this one is one of my tries

> 

```
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
>                                  message:@"Try this app called ..."
>                                     title:@"Invite to ..."
>                                      parameters:nil
>            handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
>                            if (error) {
>                          // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
>                                    NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
>                        } else {
>                     if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
>                         // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
>                       NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
>                          } else {
>                              NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
>                                   }
>                         }}];
```

the log give me the request send ...but nothing received 
Is it about the permissions setup in facebook app centre? what permissions shall I include there?

I hope I can find answer I look for days

Comment: Start again with [**this tutorial**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/) from **the beginning** to **the end**, without missing a single word. We couldn't help more.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert I will do again and inform you with result ..I hope it works this time ..thank you

Comment: this works with parseUrl method